# Angular - Click event not triggered on button

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

After I updated `angular` and `angular-cli`, I keep facing strange problems. I have two `<div>`s and I am trying to just hide one and show the other when a button clicked.

Here is my functions:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.goalView = this.el.nativeElement.getElementsByClassName('goal-view')[0];
    this.goalEdit = this.el.nativeElement.getElementsByClassName('goal-edit')[0];
  }

  triggerEdit(): void {
    this.goalView.style.display = 'none';
    this.goalEdit.style.display = 'block';
  }

  triggerView(save: boolean): void {
    this.goalEdit.style.display = 'none';
    this.goalView.style.display = 'block';
  }
```

And my template:

```
<div class="goal-view">
  ...
  <button class="ui right floated green button margin-vertical-10" (click)="triggerEdit()"><i class="ui edit icon"></i>Edit</button>
</div>
<div class="goal-edit">
  ...
  <button class="ui right floated green button margin-vertical-10"><i class="ui save icon" (click)="triggerView(true)"></i>Save</button>
</div>
```

When I click `edit` button, it works. When I click the `save` button, it works, sometimes. But sometimes it does not, I should click the button 30-40 times to make it work. I tried to just `console.log("something")` in the `triggerView` function, but it does the same. Sometimes works and sometimes does not.

I also checked the `event.target` of the `click` events:

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
    console.log(evt.target);
}, false);
```

It seems normal. It prints the correct `<button>` when I clicked.

Any idea on what should be the problem?

Comment: You have the second click listener on the image tag instead of the button tag, is that intentional?

Comment: Oh, I wasted 3 hours for that :( You are right, thanks!

Comment: @cy3er Dont post answers as comments .post it as an answer

Comment: @IsuruAb I just noticed it and wasn't sure that it's the problem. Anyway I posted an answer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the second click listener on the image tag instead of the button tag.

Answer (score 5):

Generally, you should not have to deal with direct element access inside your Component.

Rather you should switch over to using properties representing the state of elements.

Try this

```
<div class="goal-view" [hidden]="hideGoalView">
...
</div>

<div class="goal-edit" [hidden]="hideGoalEdit">
...
</div>


ngOnInit() {
   this.hideGoalView = false;
   this.hideGoalEdit = true;
}

triggerEdit(): void {
   this.hideGoalView = true;
   this.hideGoalEdit = false;
}

triggerView(save: boolean): void {
   this.hideGoalView = false;
   this.hideGoalEdit = true;
}
```

Comment: That is useful but not the problem of my code. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Does it have the same effect? Did you try it?

Comment: Yes, I know it will do the same. But I asked the problem of my code.

Comment: Nevertheless, after moving the event handler from the icon to the button, you should still follow my answer

Comment: I agree that the way you did is more "angular way". I will use that, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You add events to two different elements.

---

Method *triggerEdit* is event on **button** tag, so you can click on whole button to called it.

Method *triggerView* is event on **i** element, so you must click small area on button to call it.

---

whether I suggest you take seriously @devnull69 advice. This will save you problems in the future.